# SAS Planet exporting KML files

Tags: kml, sas

I'm new to the SAS Planet family and am having difficulties getting my head around the program. I am using 190707 version and can't export any tiles I've downloaded in a KML format back to my hard drive. It continually comes up with an error code 00E36D73. Seems if I use an earlier version of SAS Planet it's not compatible with current Google Earth. I can export the iPhone version of files but not the KML. I want to use the KML as I'm trying to convert the Google Earth images to use in my Lowrance GPS via Insight map Creator. I've watched YouTube videos of people explaining how it's done but keep getting stopped trying to export in KML format.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever get a solution?

Comment: I have a similar issue, my field “Map/Overlay layer:” is greyed out and says: “There is no supported maps”. This is only when i try and export to KML, other formats works fine.
Anyone got an idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. A work around is to use SAS.Planet.Release.181221 (lower version) and use bing maps NOT google maps to gather the data/cache the tiles. You Can then export the bing tiles as KML and run through map creator as per the youtube videos

I tried to use googlemaps with the earlier version and the export still failed.
I tried bingmaps with the latest version and that fails

I hope it gets fixed in the future but for now bing maps will have to do!

Hope this helped

I just did the entire Solent to the IOW and down to Bournemouth/portsmouth i used zoom levels 14-15-16 & 19.

IF you want it run faster on the sas.planet, you can manually zoom into the map at the correct zoom level and move about, rather than waiting for the process to step over each tile individually

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, u juste need to change the cache file.

Go to  "Settings -> Options -> Cache" and change "Default cache type" in SAS.Planet.

After this change you will be able to export a .kml

[image]